# How to run IPython notebook server with a specified URL route

Tags: python, tornado, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to run a IPython notebook server on the a predefined URL like: `http://localhost:8888/my_notebook`.

I've tried

```
$ ipython notebook --ip=localhost/my_notebook
```

which didn't work.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the configurable value from command line like this:

```
ipython notebook --NotebookApp.base_url='my_notebook'
```

Alternatively, you can set it in a config file for your profile. You can read more about it [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html).